# Sharepoint 2010 Exclusive columns?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

Does anyone know a way to have two columns in a SP2010 list that are exclusive?  I need to ensure that there is only a value for ONE column, not both.

Basically I need the following structure:

```
Category List ->  
SubCategory List (with a lookup to Category) ->  
Value (with a lookup to SubCategory).
```

But, if there is no `SubCategory`, use a lookup to `Category`. One or the other must be used, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using either a list Event Receiver (SPItemEventReceiver) or a Custom Workflow should be able to achieve these desired semantics.

I do not believe the model itself can represent such relationships. An alternative might be to have different content types, for which only one of the columns applies (to each).

Happy coding.